# Can't fix unmet dependencies in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: dependencies

So I'm having this problem really frequently and I really didn't find anything that helped me on the internet (in AskUbuntu either). I mean, I tried different stuff that unfortunately didn't work for me. I'm going to post my most recent attempt installing a package with unmet independencies:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 variety : Depends: gir1.2-gexiv2-0.10 but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: python-bs4 but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: python-cairo but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: python-configobj but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: python-dbus but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: python-gi-cairo but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: python-pil but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: python-pycurl but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: python-requests but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: gir1.2-ayatanaappindicator3-0.1 but it is not installable or
                       gir1.2-appindicator3-0.1 but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: python-httplib2 but it is not going to be installed
 wallch:i386 : Depends: libunity9:i386 (>= 3.4.6) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

So I've already tried to install manually those dependencies and this is what it outputs

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wallch:i386 : Depends: libunity9:i386 (>= 3.4.6) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Really can't find a way to fix it. I'm going to make it a little bit easier telling you guys what I've already tried

```
sudo apt-get clean 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt --fix-broken install variety
```

I've also tried to remove and reinstall the Repository. I've checked on the internet and the package is up to date, so it should be compatible with Ubuntu 17.10. I probably forgot some of the things I tried to do to fix the problem but these are some of them at least.
What can I do to fix this problem?

Comment: Can you also show the command you used to install the packages?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install variety`

Comment: of course I added the repository before it